# Data from the JSON is not displayed in the inputs of the FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have a JSON and would like to output the data from this object to the FormArray. I am only getting Object object displayed in the output. What is the best way to solve this problem and what can I do better in building the code?

My StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-data-from-api-and-populate-form-array-with-it-5kjunq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

My code:

```
// My JSON
[
  {
    "currentUser": {
      "userId": 2,
      "gender": "Herr",
      "firstname": "Max",
      "lastname": "Mustermann",
      "username": "maxMustermann",
      "email": "max-mustermann@gmail.com"
    },
    "success": true
  }
]
```

```
// My TS
 userForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('/assets/data.json').subscribe((resp: any[]) => {
      const data = resp;
      if (data && data !== null) {
        console.log('Output', data);
        this.userForm = this.fb.group({
          userFormArray: this.fb.array(
            resp.map((param) => this.generateUserFormGroup(param))
          ),
        });
      }
    });
  }

  private generateUserFormGroup(param) {
    return this.fb.group({
      gender: this.fb.control({ value: param.gender }),
      firstname: this.fb.control({ value: param.firstname }),
      lastname: this.fb.control({ value: param.lastname }),
      username: this.fb.control({ value: param.username }),
      email: this.fb.control({ value: param.email }),
    });
  }
```

```
// My Template
<form [formGroup]="userForm">
  <div formArrayName="userFormArray">
    <div
      *ngFor="
        let control of userForm.controls['userFormArray'].controls;
        let i = index
      "
    >
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <input type="text" formControlName="gender" />
        <input type="text" formControlName="firstname" />
        <input type="text" formControlName="lastname" />
        <input type="text" formControlName="username" />
        <input type="text" formControlName="email" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I this what you are looking for https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-data-from-api-and-populate-form-array-with-it-wkwfcp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @navnath I use Angular 10 and for me the function private getUserFA() does not work. I get the message map is not a function. Do you know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: check same link now. Make sure your response is an aarray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclosure: I am not an Angular developer, I'm not sure if there are consequences to the use of `new FormControl` .

First of all `param` is an object that contains another object called `currentUser` - there was an attempt to reach inaccessible fields.

I followed their docs, seems to do the job -

```
  private generateUserFormGroup(param) {
    const { currentUser } = param;
    return this.fb.group({
      gender: new FormControl(currentUser.gender),
      firstname: new FormControl(currentUser.firstname),
      lastname: new FormControl(currentUser.lastname),
      username: new FormControl(currentUser.username),
      email: new FormControl(currentUser.email)
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

[Reactive forms Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 0):

`FormBuilder` `control` takes an object containing default value and disabled state or just the default value so update your generate form method like this:

```
private generateUserFormGroup(param) {
 return this.fb.group({
  gender: this.fb.control(param.gender),
  email: this.fb.control({ value: param.email, disabled: false }),
 });
}
```

And where your are calling this function you need to pass the `currentUser`

```
this.generateUserFormGroup(data[0].currentUser)
```

Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-data-from-api-and-populate-form-array-with-it-bjg44j?file=src/app/app.component.ts)